# boost log working in exe but crashing in dll

Tags: c++, exception, dll, boost-log

> I have developed an application (application1) that uses boost::log with
> severity_channel_logger_mt and two sinks (syslog_backend &
> text_file_backend).
>
> When I run the application as an .exe, the sinks work fine and I am able to see log text files generate from messages being passed across a network, but when
> I link application1 as a .dll inside of another application (mainapp), I get
> the following errors after about 20 seconds:

```
Exception thrown at 0x00007FFA9E03CD29 in mainapp.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: boost::wrapexcept<boost::system::system_error> at memory location 0x000000F9BD9FF220.
Exception thrown at 0x00007FFA9E03CD29 in mainapp.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: [rethrow] at memory location 0x0000000000000000.
Exception thrown at 0x00007FFA9E03CD29 in mainapp.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: boost::wrapexcept<boost::system::system_error> at memory location 0x000000F9BD9FF220.
Exception thrown at 0x00007FFA9E03CD29 in mainapp.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: [rethrow] at memory location 0x0000000000000000.
Exception thrown at 0x00007FFA9E03CD29 in mainapp.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: boost::wrapexcept<boost::system::system_error> at memory location 0x000000F9BD9FF220.
Exception thrown at 0x00007FFA9E03CD29 in mainapp.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: [rethrow] at memory location 0x0000000000000000.
Exception thrown at 0x00007FFA9E03CD29 in mainapp.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: boost::wrapexcept<boost::system::system_error> at memory location 0x000000F9BD9FF220.
```

> After debugging, the exception happens in basic_sink_frontend.hpp and  core.hpp between these two calls:

basic_sink_frontend.hpp

```
backend.consume(rec, context->m_FormattedRecord);
```

core.hpp

```
BOOST_FORCEINLINE void push_record(BOOST_RV_REF(record) rec)
{
    push_record_move(static_cast< record& >(rec));
}
```

> I have verified that the "rec" variable is not NULL.
> The application1 DLL loads wihout error and I am able to run application1 functions from mainapp.
> I still see message being passed across network from syslog sink, however text_file sink logs are not generated...
> I built boost as a shared library and have the following libs in boost_1_80_0/stage/lib:
> boost_log_setup-vc142-mt-x64-1_80
> boost_log-vc142-mt-gd-x64-1_80
> boost_log-vc142-mt-x64-1_80
>
> Snippets from my code on how I use the loggers and sinks are below. Application1 uses boost::log and MainApp loads Application1 as DLL:

Application1:

```cpp
#define DEFAULT_PORT 13000
#define DEFAULT_PORT_STRING "13000"
#define DEFAULT_IP "127.0.0.1"

enum class severity_levels
{
    info,
    warning,
    error
};

void Application1::init_builtin_syslog()
{

    // Create a syslog sink
    boost::shared_ptr< sinks::synchronous_sink< sinks::syslog_backend > > sys_sink(
        new sinks::synchronous_sink< sinks::syslog_backend >());
    
    sys_sink->set_formatter
    (
        expr::stream << "Application 1 Log - ID: " << expr::attr< unsigned int >("RecordID")
            << "| " << expr::attr< severity_levels >("Severity") << ": " << expr::smessage
    );
    
    // We'll have to map our custom levels to the syslog levels
    sinks::syslog::custom_severity_mapping< severity_levels > mapping("Severity");
    mapping[severity_levels::info] = sinks::syslog::info;
    mapping[severity_levels::warning] = sinks::syslog::warning;
    mapping[severity_levels::error] = sinks::syslog::critical;
    
    sys_sink->locked_backend()->set_severity_mapper(mapping);
    
    #if !defined(BOOST_LOG_NO_ASIO)
        // Set the remote address to send syslog messages to
        sys_sink->locked_backend()->set_target_address(DEFAULT_IP, DEFAULT_PORT);
    #endif
    
    //Create a text file sink
    boost::shared_ptr< sinks::synchronous_sink< sinks::text_file_backend > > file_sink(
        new sinks::synchronous_sink< sinks::text_file_backend >(
            keywords::file_name = "application1.log",  // file name pattern
            keywords::target_file_name = "application1_%Y%m%d_%H%M%S_%2N.log",           
            keywords::rotation_size = 16384                                 
            )); 
    // Set up where the rotated files will be stored
    file_sink->locked_backend()->set_file_collector(sinks::file::make_collector(
        keywords::target = "logs",                              
        keywords::max_size = 64 * 1024 * 1024,                  
        keywords::min_free_space = 100 * 1024 * 1024,           
        keywords::max_files = 512                           
        ));
    
    // Upon restart, scan the target directory for files matching the file_name pattern
    file_sink->locked_backend()->scan_for_files();
    
    file_sink->set_formatter
    (
        expr::format("%1% Application 1 Log - ID: %2% | %3% : \"%4%\"")
        % expr::attr< boost::posix_time::ptime >("TimeStamp")
        % expr::attr< unsigned int >("RecordID")
        % expr::attr< severity_levels >("Severity")
        % expr::smessage
    );
    
    // Add the sinks to the core
    logging::core::get()->add_sink(sys_sink);
    logging::core::get()->add_sink(file_sink);
    
    // Add logging attributes
    logging::core::get()->add_global_attribute("RecordID", attrs::counter< unsigned int >());
    logging::core::get()->add_global_attribute("TimeStamp", attrs::utc_clock());

}

int start()
{
   init_builtin_syslog();
   src::severity_channel_logger_mt\< severity_levels \> lg(keywords::severity = severity_levels::info, keywords::channel = "Application 1");

   for (int i = 0; i \< 10000; ++i)
   {
      BOOST_LOG_SEV(lg, severity_levels::info) \<\< infoLog;
      if(runexe) std::cout \<\< "App1 sent: " \<\< infoLog \<\< std::endl;
      boost::this_thread::sleep_for(boost::chrono::milliseconds(1000));
   }
return 0;
}
```

MainApp:

```
bool loadedApp1 = false; 
std::atomic<bool> startApp1 = true;  
std::atomic<char*> app1Err((char*)""); 

HINSTANCE app1dll;
void printError( const TCHAR* msg );

typedef void (*MYPROC2)(std::atomic<bool>&, std::atomic<char*>&);
MYPROC2 app1start;

int main()
{

std::cout << "Starting application 1... " << std::endl;
        try
        {
            app1dll = LoadLibrary(TEXT("application1.dll"));
            if(app1dll == NULL)
            {
                std::cerr << "Application 1 DLL load library failure." << GetLastError() << '\n';
                loadedApp1 = false;
            }
            else
            {
                loadedApp1 = true;
                 app1start = (MYPROC2) GetProcAddress(app1dll, MAKEINTRESOURCEA(1)); 
                if (NULL != app1start) 
                {
                    std::thread t1(app1start, std::ref(startApp1), std::ref(app1Err));
                    t1.detach();
                    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(4000));
                }      
                if(startApp1.load() == false)
                {
                    std::cout << "Error starting Application 1: " << app1Err.load() << std::endl;
                }
            }
}
 catch(const std::exception& e)
{
    std::cerr << e.what() << '\n';
    return 1;
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: `0x0000000000000000` enable break on access violation and use your debugger to try to understand what variable is a nullpointer.

Comment: With msvc make sure you are not mixing debug and release. It's not usually safe to use debug libraries in release or release libraries in debug unless care is taken to isolate the CRT and ABI differences.

Comment: A recurrent problem with DLLs is uninitialized global data, that is especially true on Windows.   A common solution is to use a dll_init(') function and singletons.

Comment: Second observation: I don't think main() is called in Windows dlls, the application should initialte the call to init_builtin_syslog(), before calling any other functions.  Do not try to initialize anything from DllMain(), that will not work, since the global data will be reset after DllMain() exits.  It's frustrating, but that''s Windows.

Comment: Please cut your example down to one clear example program. And at that point you might well solve your own problem.

Comment: @drescherjm i updated post with call that throws exception. The variable passed to the function is not null:  rec = {m_impl=0x0000024e26540150 {m_ref_counter={value_=1 } m_attribute_values={m_pImpl=0x0000024e26543540 {...} } } }

Comment: @Michaël Roy you are correct, I have a DLLMain in application1 which allows it to function as DLL, that main above is not the true main() it's actually a start function. sorry for confusion. i will change it

Comment: In your application main(), there is a try {} block, but no catch statement.  Where is it? The error message indicate that there is a rethrow with a NULL pointer ?? . The error should be related to these exceptions.   You can configire the MSVC IDE's debugger to break on exceptions, this would help you locate where and why the error happens.

Comment: What is the contents of `rec` ?   Are all of its members valid?  Have you tried handling the boost::system::system_error exception, to see if it ends up being unhadled?

Comment: Maybe related to this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64551392/boost-log-and-dynamically-loaded-libraries

Comment: @MichaëlRoy i updated the try catch (copy/paste error) and added to the details what function is throwing the exception. thanks for the feedback

Comment: @MichaëlRoy rec = {m_impl=0x0000024e26540150 {m_ref_counter={value_=1 } m_attribute_values={m_pImpl=0x0000024e26543540 {...} } } } it looks as if the values are non-null at the time of the exception

Comment: It definoitely looks like an unintialized global variable.  can you confirm that Application1::init_builtin_syslog() has elready executed in full, while called from the application  before this error occurs?